# Accessing to a IBOutlet of another class

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a lot of different `UIViewController`.
In one of this ViewController I want to change the IBOutlet of another `UIViewController`. The error is : `found nil while unwrapping an optional value`.
But the textView is not "nil".

```
import UIKit

class WeirdViewController: UIViewController {

    let third = ThirdViewController()

@IBAction func font1(sender: AnyObject) {

        third.textView.text = "try"
  }   

}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend you to use UIViews instead of UIViewControllers.

Comment: How did you declare textView property in ThirdViewController? It should be something like this: @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

Comment: Yes it is. @RomanSalabay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you are creating new ThirdViewController

```
let third = ThirdViewController()
```

and in this case third.textView is nil.

What you need is to get reference to the existing object of ThirdViewController which is inside of UIScrollView and then change value of textView.text

Comment: Ok, and how can I get the reference of the existing object ?

Comment: In place where you instantiate your ViewControllers and add them to UIScrollView you should have references to both WeirdViewController and ThirdViewController.